# Getting a Python Error with OpenLayers in QGIS 2.18.15

Tags: qgis, openlayers, error

So I just recently converted to QGIS from pen and paper, and it was all fine until I opened some layers and tried to use OpenLayers for a Google Satellite view. A yellow bar appeared at the top of the screen saying "**Python error:** An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details."

Here is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/brana/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
    self._addLayerCallback(self)
  File "C:/Users/brana/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 182, in addLayer
    self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
  File "C:/Users/brana/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 231, in setMapCrs
    extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
QgsCsException: forward transform of
(110051.440661, 34780.826688)
PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits
```

As you can see, the error code says "latitude or longitude exceeded limits," but even when I zoom in to a reasonable scale (1:2500) I still get the error.

Any fixes?

I am completely new to QGIS and really only know the basic functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to fix it by going to the layer properties and changing the Coordinate Reference System from "Project CRS" to "Selected CRS."

Or going into project properties and unchecking the box that says "Enable 'On the fly' CRS transformation (OTF)."

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the OpenLayers plugin - it's very buggy. Use the QuickMapServices plugin instead.

Comment: That is what I have heard about OpenLayers-- I just keep forgetting to convert to QMS lol.

Comment: @ndawson: Where do you configure that? I have the above mentioned error, the one that camerakid posted, and I cannot work!!!