# QGIS 3.2.2 OpenLayers plugin isn't listed to install

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've just installed QGIS 3.2.2 and after installation, tried to use the Plug in Manager to install the OpenLayers plugin.  But it's not in the list to install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Straight from a core QGIS developer - "Don't use the OpenLayers plugin - it's very buggy. Use the QuickMapServices plugin instead." [source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269816/2856)

Comment: You can also use the method described here: https://www.giscourse.com/how-to-add-openstreetmap-basemaps-in-qgis-3-0/

Comment: Also in the browser pane, under XYZ tiles you can use Open Street Maps data.

Comment: Try this one also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-WfXHbGOlw

Comment: Well Done, It was really easy to add connections and use google maps without the use of openlayer plugin. very helpful.

Answer (score 24):

**The OpenLayers Plugin is deprecated.**

It is recommended to use `QuickMapServices` or [QGIS core functionality](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670) instead of OpenLayers Plugin because the latter has many issues. One very famous issue is the projection.

[image]
**If you still want to use the OpenLayers Plugin**

You need to check `Show also experimental plugin` from the `Plugin manager -> Settings` because OpenLayers Plugin is listed under experimental plugins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The QuickMapServices plugin doesn't have Google Maps.

Comment: @DonnyV. Use `Search QMS` and write Google in the search bar, and your will get Google Maps.

Answer (score 3):

I am using QGIS 3.10. On the menu bar click on View---> Panels ---> Browser.

[image]

Select the Browser tab then select the layer you want from the XYZ Tiles:

[image]

If you wish to add tiles from other providers, just right click on the XYZ Tile folder and choose "New Connection".

Below are some connections I have taken from this page: 
(https://geogeek.xyz/how-to-add-google-maps-layers-in-qgis-3.html)

```
Google Maps: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Google Satellite: http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Google Satellite Hybrid: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Google Terrain: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

Google Roads: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Solution is here https://youtu.be/67ZruLlGdJs
Watch the above video and there is a link for Google map satellite and other maps.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take our [tour].  Please [edit] your answer to provide complete steps required to solve the problem and explanation on how and why it works.  Links to other sites or videos can be used to support your answer, but link-only posts are not sufficient as the links may change or disappear over time.  Link-only answers may be deleted.