# Installing OpenLayers Plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am unable to identify the 'OpenLayer plugin' to install. I have not installed it but it is also not showing up in the list of 'Not installed plugins'.

How can I get around this and get this plugin installed or there is another plugin that performs the same function of generating a base map?

Answer (score 1):

There's another plugin named [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in this post:

[QGIS 3.2.2 OpenLayers plugin isn't listed to install](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295097/qgis-3-2-2-openlayers-plugin-isnt-listed-to-install)

Basically, QuickMapServices is a much better plugin and if you really want OpenLayers plugin, enable experimental plugins in settings.